# Python pandas: more efficiently looking up the maximum of a column in other rows?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, processing-efficiency

**Context**

I have a .csv of process steps that each have a finishing date & time, but their starting times are unknown. I want to determine the time at which the items in these processes arrive at a department. This can be computed by checking the 'Chain' of PredecessorProcessCode

So the .csv fields are structured as follows:

- ProcessCode (identifier of process, there may be multiple processes at a ProcessDepartment in a chain. While some may start earlier, they could finish later due to divergence - see ItemNumber)
- PredecessorProcessCode (ProcessCode of process previosu in 'chain')
- FinishDateTime (time at which process is done)
- ItemStartDateTime (arrival of item in process, = lowest datetime in 'chain')
- ProcessDepartment (department of process)
- ItemNumber (an item diverges to multiple 'process chains' along the process)
- PrevDepartment (preceding department)

Basically, I want to add a field named 'PreviousDepartmentFinishDateTime' to be able to determine WIP amounts, queues etc.. for the Processes. But, the 'PredecessorProcessCode' is not necessarily the finishing time at the previous department, as the predecessor of the predecessor may have started earlier, while finishing later. So basically, my process now is as follows:

1. Determine predecessor chain (so recursively look until no more predecessor, simple function) of the item
2. Check which predecessors are in the previous department (using a dict)
3. Check which predecessor of the item has the latest FinishDateTime at the previous department.
4. Add this as a new column to the row of the current Item-ProcessCode

**Now, here's my problem:**
I've loaded the 4 million rows and am able to determine to add the column'PreviousDepartmentFinishDateTime', but at only around 500 rows per second, meaning that I now wait over 2 hours for the new column to be added. I must improve the speed of this process, as we intend to use it 'online'.

Step 3. of the previous process is seemingly too slow. I need about 2ms per lookup resulting in the long waiting time.

I now have a df with multiindex ItemNumber - ProcessCode

A code snippet is as follows:

```html
def prev_department_finished(row):
  itemno, processcode = row.name

  processcode_predecessors = processesbefore(processcode)
  prevdepartment = row['PrevDepartment']
  df_subset = df.loc[itemno].query('Department == @prevdepartment & ProcessCode in processcode_predecessors')['FinishDateTime']
  if df_subset.empty: #if no preceding department
    return row['ItemStartDateTime']
  else:
    return df_subset.max()
    


df['PrevDepartmentDone'] = df.apply(prev_department_finished, axis=1)
```

My main question is therefore:

- Is using .loc efficient? I've looked it up but can't seem to get around using (as .at is faster but doesnt allow looking up multiple rows). For the most part .loc 'knows where to look', as I understand its basically a dictionary lookup with the ItemNumber & ProcessCode, yet, it takes 2ms on average (is this due to the 4M rows??)